# How to invoke Axios synchronously in React?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, axios, react-hooks

I'm using the Axios in React to register a user into MongoDb database.
But before I register a user, I check if that user already exists in the database, but since axios.post() is asynchronous, the rest of the code precending this response executes and user with same Id is regsitered again.

How do I solve this. PFB my code:

const validateRegister = (values) => {

```
let errors={};

const patternName = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z ]{3,20}$')
const patternPhone =  new RegExp('^[0-9]{9,10}$')
const patternEmail = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9._:$!%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]$')
const patternPassword = new RegExp('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.{8,})')

if(!values.name || !patternName.test(values.name)){
    errors.name="Please enter a valid name"
}
if(!values.phone || !patternPhone.test(values.phone)){
    errors.phone="Please enter a valid Phone number of 9-10 digits"
}
if(!values.email || !patternEmail.test(values.email)){
    errors.email="Please enter a valid email address"
}
if(!values.password || !patternPassword.test(values.password)){
    errors.password="Please enter a strong password to continue. A strong password has: Atleast 8 characters in length, 2 letters in upper case, 1 special character (!@#$&*), 2 number (0-9), 3 letters in lower case"
}

if(!values.isTermsAndConditionsAccepted){
    errors.isTermsAndConditionsAccepted = "Please Accept the Terms and conditions"
}

//Check if the user already exist

if(values.phone){
      
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('phone', values.phone);

    console.log('inside user check')

    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/doesUserExistByPhone', formData).then(response => {

        //Success - then create account
        
    }).catch(errorResponse=>{

        console.log(errorResponse)
        if(errorResponse.response.status===409){
            console.log('User already exist');  
            errors.phone="User Already exist. If you've already registered. Please try to Login.";
            return errors;
        }
        else if(errorResponse.response.status===500){
            errors.phone = "Unable to register user, contact SwapiFi Support";
            return errors;
        }
    
    })

}

console.log('Errors found before creating user: ', errors);

return errors;
```

}

export default validateRegister

I invoke this Validator from another js file:

const useFormRegister = (submitForm) => {

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
const [dataIsCorrect, setDataIsCorrect] = useState(false);

const  [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    isTermsAndConditionsAccepted: false
})

const handleValueChangeEvent = (event) => {

    setValues({
        ...values,
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value,

    })
    
}

const handleRegisterEvent = (event) => {
    console.log('Register button clicked');
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validation(values));
    
    console.log('Errors-Phone:', errors)

    setDataIsCorrect(true);

    
}

useEffect(() => {

    console.log('No. of errors:', Object.keys(errors).length)

    {Object.entries(errors).map(([key, value]) => (
        console.log("Error, ", key, ':', value)
    ))}

    if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && dataIsCorrect){
        
        submitForm(true);
        let formData = new FormData();
    
        {Object.entries(values).map(([key, value]) => (
        formData.append(key, value)
        ))}

        console.log(formData)

        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/registerUser', formData).then(response => {console.log(response)}).catch(error=>{console.log(error)})

    }
}, [errors])


return {handleValueChangeEvent, handleRegisterEvent, values, errors};
```

}

export default useFormRegister

Comment: use `async` - `await` syntax

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to fire off a check synchronously. Look into [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax. You can write code that "looks" synchronous but will actually execute asynchronously. This will allow you to do something like:

```
 const checkUserExists = async (user) => {
    const repsonse = await axios('/check/user/endpoint');
    const user = await response.json();

    return !!user;
 }

 const registerUser = async (user) => {
    const repsonse = await axios('/register/user/endpoint');
    const data = await response.json();

    // do stuff here
 }
```

and now you can implement whatever logic you need around these functions

Answer (score -2):

```
useEffect(()=>{
   async function deal(){
      let data = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000")
      setDeal(..)
   }
   deal()
},[])
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Consider adding a short description

Comment: @mchowdam This is not a "comment". Code-only answers are still answers, and the correct response is downvoting (and maybe posting a comment recommending the poster to include an explanation), and then picking "Looks OK" in the review.